# prepend string to entire column in mongodb

Tags: string, mongodb, prepend

I would like to prepend a string to all values of a mongo collection's column.

Something like

```
 db.testcoll.update({},{$set:{column1 : "prependstring"+ column1}});
```

Is there something like this ?

Comment: You will need to retrieve, modify, and update each document. You can use the aggregation framework as explained in an answer below, but it will produce a new set of documents, not modify the old. You can use the `$out` stage to save the new documents to a new collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can be achieved using the `$concat` operator in an aggregation pipeline.

```
db.testcoll.aggregate([{
  $project: {
    column1: {
      $concat: ['prependstring', '$column1']
    }
  }
}]);
```

As specified in the official MongoDB docs ([here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)) the `$concat` operator only works with strings.

Comment: You will also need to project all of the other fields in the document to get output documents that look like the originals. The aggregation pipeline creates new documents from old, do you will need to use `$out` to save to a new collection.

Comment: @wdberkeley Indeed. In order to permanently change the collection, the $out stage must be specified, together with the name of the output collection

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a pipeline, you can run a simple forEach loop to make the change:

```
var recs = db.testcoll.find({});

recs.forEach(function(rec) {
  if (rec. column1.indexOf("prependstring") == 0) { // In case we run it more than once
    return;
  }
  var newval = "prependstring" + rec.column1;
  db.vouchers.update({_id: rec._id}, {$set: {column1: newval}});
});
```

Note that depending on the number of records and your cluster setup, it can be quite slow compared to the pipeline option.